# C# dictionary to array

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this:

```
void SaveMultiple(Dictionary<string, decimal> updates)
{
ColumnSet cs = new ColumnSet();
cs.Attributes = new string[] { "att1", "att2", "add3" };
}
```

My attributes array needs to be all the string values of the dictionary.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Just as a note, in a `Dictionary<string, int>`, the strings are called the **key** (left hand side), the ints are called the **value** (right hand side). Important distinction to make, as keys are forcibly unique, whereas values are not.

Answer (score 4):

You mean the keys of this dictionary? Then `updates.Keys.ToArray()` will give them to you.

Answer (score 3):

```
cs.Attributes = updates.Keys.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cs.Attributes = updates.Values.ToArray();
```

if you want the Values
or

```
cs.Attributes = updates.Keys.ToArray();
```

if you want the Keys (most likely as shown in your code snippet)

Comment: At least convert them to string before arrayzing them :-)

Answer (score 0):

```css
void SaveMultiple(Dictionary<string,decimal> updates) 
{
  ColumnSet cs=new ColumnSet();
  cs.Attributes=updates.Keys.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.